# What is the difference between reducer and action creator function?

Tags: redux

While reading Redux official docs I see that there are `actions`, `action creator functions` and `reducers`.

What is the difference between `reducer` and `action creator function`? Are they the same thing or are they different things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Reducer` and `Action creator` are two different things. To quote the [Redux doc](https://redux.js.org/basics), Action creators are

> Action creators are exactly that—functions that create actions

And Reducers are

> Reducers specify how the application's state changes in response to actions sent to the store

`Action creators` are functions that create and return `actions`. Whereas, `Reducers` are functions that specify how the state changes based on a particular `action`. So `Reducers` intercept the `actions` created by the `action creators` and modify the application `state` accordingly.